# opencv conversion from a Mat element to IplImage *

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv

How can I convert a Mat element to IplImage * element? Please Help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Mat mat_img;
//....
IplImage ipl_img = mat_img;
```

This puts a header of `IplImage` on top of `mat_img` so there is no copying. You can pass `&ipl_img` to function which need `IplImage*`.

Comment: @Jacob how to do it in java??

Answer (score 1):

**Mat to IplImage :**

```
IplImage *image = new IplImage(mat_img);
```

**IplImage to Mat :**

```
Mat image(ipl_img);
```