# Mat and setMouseCallback function

Tags: c++, c, opencv, iplimage

I have a `my_mouse_callback` example function that works with IplImage*:

```
void my_mouse_callback(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param) 
{
IplImage* image = (IplImage*) param;
switch( event ) 
{
    case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN: 
        drawing_box = true;
        box = cvRect(x, y, 0, 0);
        break;
        ...

        draw_box(image, box);
        break;
}
```

which is implemented in `main` like this:

```
cvSetMouseCallback(Box Example,my_mouse_callback,(void*) image);
```

The problem is, in my code I'm using Mat object and it can't be transfered this way to the `setMouseCallback` function.

I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve transfering Mat to IplImage*.

Or if there is no solution, how can I correctly convert Mat to IplImage*?

I tried that already with this code from the opencv documentation:

```
Mat I;
IplImage* pI = &I.operator IplImage();
```

and it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [no equivalent](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/highgui._high-level_gui_and_media_io.html) of that function in the C++ interface as far as I can tell.

But you can convert a `cv::Mat` to an `IplImage*` [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017425/opencv-conversion-from-a-mat-element-to-iplimage/3018880#3018880), and the other way around like this:

```
cv::Mat mat(my_IplImage);
```

Comment: Ty, your answer lead me to solution,

    IplImage* ipl_img = new IplImage (mat_image);

then I was able to use:

    setMouseCallback( imageName, onMouse, (void*) &ipl_img );

Comment: That was the idea. By the way, there's a little checkbox near my answer, you can click on it to select it as the official answer to your question. Good luck, and welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you transfer a Mat to your MouseCallback function?  You just did it with an IplImage.  Mats are just pointers.  Here's how I did it.

```
void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    Mat src;
    src = *((Mat*)param);

   ...
```

and called it like so in my main loop:

```
 setMouseCallback("source", onMouse, &src);
```